# Binary Tree static methods in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, static-methods

I have these instance methods in my Java implementation of Binary Tree and Search Binary Tree: `getSize()`, `getHeight()`, `getDepth()`, `getPreOrder()`, `getInOrder()`, `getPostOrder()` and `getLevelOrder()`. These methods use the root of the tree in others recursive methods that have a parameter `Node`. Which is more appropiate to use from the point of view of the OOP:

1. Using these recursive methods as static methods, because they use an object (`Node`) that doesn't belong to the actual class, and they don't use any class attributes,
2. They can be instance methods because they can use in a subtree of this tree and they don't use any static attributes,
3. or they may be in other static class like `UtilsTree()`?

Comment: `they use an object (Node)` then they can be non-static methods of `Node`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an OOP perspective I believe approach number 2 is the way to go. (Statics are in general often frowned upon in OOP.)

As I understand it, the method uses `this` as root, and then traverses the rest of the tree without calling any instance methods? This isn't too bad considering that the other nodes are of the same class, which means that the code is already shared among all objects. (The method can access private members of other instances and so forth.)

That being said, I think `getSize`, `getHeight`, `getDepth`, `getPreOrder`, `getInOrder`, `getPostOrder` and `getLevelOrder` can all be implemented as proper recursive instance methods. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

A fourth option which isn't too bad would be to use a visitor pattern and have a `NodeVisitor` interface.

Comment: Therefore, in OOP, Is it better to do instance recursive methods than static recursive methods?

Comment: I would argue that that is preferable. Although I think the reasons for that is more on readability and grasping how the code works rather than object orientation principles. I mean traversing the subtree within the method of the root object doesn't violate encapsulation or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Some of those methods definitely should be non-static members since they relate directly to a specific instance.

`tree.getSize()` or `tree.getDepth()` is much easier to read and understancd than `BinaryTree.getDepth(tree)`.

However one could argue that the methods `getPreOrder()`, `getInOrder()`, `getPostOrder()` can be static or even in their own class.  You can think of that as a `StrategyPattern` for how to walk the tree.

TraversalStrategy.PREORDER.walk(tree);

might be a good idea instead of adding more methods.  That way, if you ever need to add different ways to walk to the tree you don't have to keep adding methods to `BinaryTree` (Following the Open-Closed Principle)

Comment: I think tree.getSize() is the better way to obtain the size of the tree, but the recursive method, which is called by getSize() as getSize(root), could use a node that isn't in the tree like this tree.getSize(nodeOtherTree) and for that I have the question about if these methods may be static or not...

Comment: you can make those static they don't have to be public though

Answer (score 0):

A `class` represents a pattern for a set of `Object`s. A `class` can have `static` members and methods, that is, `class`-level properties and abilities. An instance of a class is an `Object`, which has its particular, non-`static` members and methods. In your case, we are talking about a bunch of getters. The key question is:

> whose are those methods?

and the answer is: they are methods, that is, abilities of your `Tree` `Object`. If you have several `Tree`s, the other `Tree`s have nothing to do with the size and stuff of a given `Tree`. As a result, all the mentioned methods should be `public`, instance-level methods unless you want to use them internally, in which case the affected methods should be `protected`, non-`static` methods.

Comment: The answer is correct, but these methods use a recursive methods that have a parameter Node which can be Node of the others trees. The question "whose are those methods?" is not as intuitive for this case.

Comment: In fact, it is. You are trying to find a node in the Tree you are processing. It is not relevant that another Tree actually contains the same Node. Your approach should be agnostic, so, if you later try to search a Node which is not present in another Tree, your approach would still be logically viable. Never assume that your current situation will be applicable forever.

Comment: Yes, it is right, but is not intuitive that you can find a Node of another instace Tree using actual instance Tree e.g. `BTree Tree = new Tree();
BTree AnotherTree = new Tree();
Tree.createTree(Node);
AnotherTree.createTree(NodeOfAnotherTree);
Tree.getSize(NodeOfAnotherTree);`

Comment: I call this a coincidence. In my view the focus is on the fact that I am searching for the Node inside the current Tree instance. If this does not feel right for you, then you can invent your own strategy, but make sure it is compatible with your teammates, it is effective and easy to use. In my view it is not relevant where the Node comes from, the relevant thing is that we are searching the Node in the tree.

Comment: I think that you consider that Node and NodeOfAnotherTree are the same but it isn't. The recursive method traverse the Tree because the Nodes have an attribute child and for that you could obtain the size of the tree through of this actual Node. The problem is when you do this ` `Tree.getSize(NodeOfAnotherTree)` you obtain the size of AnotherTree not the size of Tree.

Comment: You are searching for similar Node as the parameter in the Tree object.